# Axios возвращает ошибку даже при статусе 200

Tags: javascript, reactjs, golang

например есть метод:

```
   async getComments(data = {}) {
        const result = await HTTP.post('/', data);
        if (result) {
            return result;
        }
    }
```

ну и сам метод post()

```
    static post(url, data, params) {
    return axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: backendDomen + url,
        data: data,
        params: params
    }).then(function (value) {
        console.log(value)
        return value
    }).catch(function (reason) {
        console.log(reason)
        return reason.response
    })
}
```

Запрос OPTIONS возвращает статус 200, хедеры, но запрос POST не идет а в консоли я вижу ошибку

`Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)`

на сервере:

```
 func main() {
    gocron.Every(1).Hour().Do(writeInDB)

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/", List)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

хендлер:

```
func List(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request)  {
    var results CommentsCollection
    response.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    response.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
    response.Header().Set("Access-Control-Request-Method", "GET, POST")
    response.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    response.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)


    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(request.Body, 1048576))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    if err := request.Body.Close(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var dateInterval DateInterval

    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &dateInterval); err != nil {
        if err := json.NewEncoder(response).Encode(err); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    session, err := mgo.Dial(MongoHost)

    if err!= nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer session.Close()

    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    var emptyTime time.Time
    var err2 error
    if dateInterval.Start != emptyTime && dateInterval.End != emptyTime {
        err2 = session.DB("parser").C("comments").Find(bson.M{"date": bson.M{"$gte": dateInterval.Start, "$lte": dateInterval.End}}).All(&results)
    } else {
        err2 = session.DB("parser").C("comments").Find(nil).All(&results)
    }

    if err2 != nil {
        panic(err2)
    }

    jsonResponse, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    io.WriteString(response, string(jsonResponse))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`200` у `OPTIONS`, означает лишь то, что удалось получить параметры соединения с ресурсом. Они (параметры) могут совпасть с параметрами вашего запроса, могут не совпасть. Если не совпадают, то на основной запрос вы получите что-то вроде: `405 Method Not Allowed`. Но это так, к слову.

А вам надо в `catch`, написать `console.log(reason.response)` вместо `console.log(reason)`. Должно помочь.

Comment: Как мне это может помочь? Он запрос не отправляет, хотя все идеально работает. Какая мне разница что там в консоль вываодится. я в постмане проверяю, возвращается статус 200 и данные

Comment: У вас ошибка, Network Error at createError (createError.js:16). Вот похожий вопрос обсуждается [https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/960)

Comment: Мне не понятно в чем заключается ошибка. console.log(reason.response) выводит undefined. Похожий вопрос обсуждается, но ответа на него нет, кто то там же пишет что тоже undefined выводится

Comment: Ещё такая ошибка есть Failed to load http://localhost:8080/: Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Ага... вам надо добавить на вашем сервере `Content-Type` к `allowedHeaders` для этого запроса. Как это сделать - зависит от того типа сервера, который вы используете.

Comment: Я написал простенький сервер на го с помощью библиотеки github.com/gorilla/mux

Comment: Вроде у меня была похожая проблема, но в том случае у меня был бекенд на Laravel, я сейчас смотрю на заголовки что он возвращает, там нет ни Access-Control-Request-Method ни Access-Control-Allow-Headers но все же работает

Comment: Что интересно, оно вдруг заработало, хотя я ничего не сделал